# Apache Shiro authc.loginUrl no redirect to my jersey services after login

Tags: java, apache, rest, jersey, shiro

**I want to secure my jersey JAX-RS services with Apache Shiro security *with out JSP*
but its not working.**

when i use browser to test my services the server redirect me to login page
as expected and when i insert username and password and then press submit button
**the server does not redirect me back to the service after login**.

i am getting this Error: **HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /rest/hello/some_text. Reason:  Not Found Powered by Jetty://**

the code I working on it can be download from here https://github.com/javajack/shiro-jersey.git
and look for **sub project "jersey-sample"**
i only modified the  shiro.ini and change the: "authcBasic" to "authc".

i test it with my browser: **url: localhost:port/rest/hello/some_text**

what am i missing ?

the following is my configuration:

shiro.ini:

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /connect.html

[users]
root = secret,admin
guest = guest,guest
presidentskroob = 12345,president
darkhelmet = ludicrousspeed,darklord,schwartz
lonestarr = vespa,goodguy,schwartz

[roles]
admin = *
schwartz = lightsaber:*
goodguy = winnebago:drive:eagle5

[urls]
/connect.html = authc
/rest/** = authc
```

web.xml:

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>rest web application JAX-RS with Security Framework</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.shiro.jersey.sample</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.shiro.jersey.ShiroResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

AdminSecretsResource.java

```
package org.apache.shiro.jersey.sample;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation.RequiresRoles;

@Path("/admin")
@RequiresRoles("admin")
public class AdminSecretsResource {

   @GET
   public Response tellSecret() {
      final String output = "Shh, the secret answer is 41.";
      return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
   }

}
```

HelloWorldResource .java

```
package org.apache.shiro.jersey.sample;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldResource {

   @GET
   @Path("/{message}")
   public Response sayHello(@PathParam("message") String message) {
      String output = "Jersey says : " + message;
      return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
   }

}
```

connect.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Apache Shiro Tutorial Webapp : Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <style> body{padding-top:20px;} </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form name="loginform" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username or Email" name="username" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="rememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true"> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-jersey-root</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-sample</artifactId>
    <name>Apache Shiro :: Samples :: Jersey</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>[1.2.1,2.0.0)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>[1.2.1,2.0.0)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>[1.10,2.0)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>[1.10,2.0)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.26</version>
                <configuration>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>9080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <requestLog implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
                        <filename>./target/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</filename>
                        <retainDays>90</retainDays>
                        <append>true</append>
                        <extended>false</extended>
                        <logTimeZone>GMT</logTimeZone>
                    </requestLog>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: if i use authcBasic instead of authc the after post my username and password in the popup login i get Error 404 not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your *shiro.ini* configuration file to add the login page to the form authentication filter as below:

- *shiro.ini*:

  ```
  [urls]
  /connect.html = authc
  /rest/** = authc
  ```

This would say to the Shiro engine to process any request along with the authentication request (*/connect.html*) using the [FormAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/trunk/web/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/FormAuthenticationFilter.java).
Those paths are complementory and should be both specified to work correctly.

Comment: i get this error when i modified your suggestion HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /rest/hello/some_text Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

Comment: i update my question as you suggested but i got the same error as befor HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing "/rest/hello/some_text"

Comment: Are there any errors on logs?
Could you remove the *loginUrl* section from *shiro.ini* and rename the *connect.htm* to *login.jsp*.

Comment: ok your suggestion lead me to the answer the HTTP ERROR 404 was mistake in my web.xml configuration file tnks tmarwen you make my day